# Salesforce : Mass Delete EmailMessage

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a salesforce developer account on salesforce and

I am not able to delete mass **EmailMessage**.

I can see Task object and I can delete that but I want only email messages to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your name >Set up> Data Management> Mass Delete Records> Mass Delete Activities.>
Step 2: Find Activities that match the following criteria:>Subject Equals Email> Select checkbox that you want to delete > click Delete